# How to set usb serial string on stm32f4?

Tags: stm32

I have a custom board with a stm32f427 running nuttx.  Currently the device is configured as a cdc_acm usb device.  The usb serial string defaults to 0.  I would like to be able to set the serial number so that I can connect multiple devices to one computer via usb.  I have looked through the source code and read the datasheets and it has not been much help.  Does anyone know how to do this or where I should look?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just programmed the serial string into OTP flash memory and edited the cdc_acm driver to grab the string from that location.  The only problem with this solution is if you mess up the serial number, you can't change it.  It's locked in forever.